# Program running fine inside Pycharm, but running its cli.exe from the command prompt giving error

Tags: python, cmd, command-line-interface

I have created an executable `cli.exe` for my python module named `abc`. `abc` is running fine inside pycharm but when i run my cli.exe from the cmd prompt, it is giving the following error:

```
Failed to load logging configuration
Exception occurred inside main() method
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ProjectionFiles\projectionStartup.py", line 15, in main
    logobj = ApcLogging(args[3])
  File "ProjectionFiles\logging.py", line 58, in __init__
    raise e
  File "ProjectionFiles\logging.py", line 16, in __init__
    fileConfig(logfile)
  File "logging\config.py", line 71, in fileConfig
  File "logging\config.py", line 104, in _create_formatters
  File "configparser.py", line 958, in __getitem__
KeyError: 'formatters'
```

I am at my wits end as to what to do to resolve this as the very same code runs flawlessly inside pycharm.

The way i am running cli.exe in cmd prompt is: `cli.exe parameter1 parameter2 parameter3`

And i am also running my executable from the same directory where the module is kept(errors say it all, because I think it entered the program and then threw an error)

Any help will be sincerely appreciated.

Comment: What's `logfile`? It looks like it's misformatted (missing the `formatters` key).

Comment: Also, does the program work if you run it using `python ...` (i.e. without having packaged it into `cli.exe`)?

Comment: It runs fine inside pycharm using python interpreter.` Logfile` is also correctly constructed and all. Thus asking, what could be the possible reason for .exe to throw an error?

Comment: Does it run fine on the command line using the Python interpreter is what I was asking. It looks like it's trying to read a misformatted `logfile` from somewhere.

Comment: I didnt try doing that. Infact I dont know how to do what you are asking for. I am just starting out in the world of python and development.

Comment: How did you end up with `cli.exe` anyway?